# how to get the data from excel file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel

Here i want to get the Data from Excel File by using upload file control.My Snippet is

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function my_function() {
       var Excel;
       Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
       Excel.Visible = false;
       return Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Bennu.xlsx").ActiveSheet.Cells(l, i).Value;
   }
   var i = 1;
   var l = 1;

   do {
       a = my_function()

       if (a != null) {
           document.write("value is " + a + "&nbsp ;&nbsp ;&nbsp ;&nbsp ;");
           i++;
       }
       else {
           l++;
           i = 1;
           document.write("<br />");
       }

       b = my_function()
   } while (a != null || b != null);
```

When i run this on i didn`t get any thing

Comment: You don't. This would be a massive exploit if a web page was able to do this.

Comment: @Phylogenesis can you explain in detail please...

Comment: Consider the fact that you want to be able to read the specified file off the user's hard disk. Replace your request for that Excel file with a request to open the user's local password file, or a document containing their bank details, or a cookie file for a website and you have problems.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation...is there any alternate way to do this...

Comment: A couple, but nothing even close to simple. You could [read the file using the FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and parse it.

Comment: @Phylrogenesis:Thanks for you Reply

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems there, the chief amongst them being that you're using an ActiveX object. That will only work in IE, and only in old versions of it, only if the user has it enabled, and only if the page is running in a trusted/intranet zone. No browser other than IE supports ActiveX objects, and even IE doesn't anymore.

Separately, using `document.write` after initial page load will wipe the page out.

Comment: can you please give me any example to get the data from Excel by using java script........

Comment: @user4491399: In a browser? A quick search shows [this project](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) which says it can read XLSX files; there are probably others. You'll need to be using a browser that supports the File API and you'll need to have the user (not code) specify what file to use.

Comment: :Thanks for your Reply